# Unable to accept cookies in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, automation

I am trying to do webscrapping using selenium in python. When the new browser opens the accept cookies button pop up and the scraping stopped.The button location is - Accept Cookies
I am using the the following code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
```

However the button is not clicking automatically.

[image]

[image]

```
<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler" tabindex="0">Accept Cookies</button>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: It seems the element must be inside an `iframe` or under shadow root. If possible share the url.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I have done it. The code is working and able to click the Accept cookies button automatically. Along with the above codes I have added-

```
 SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5
```